# how to make thread2 wait for thread1 in c using posix-threads

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, mutex

I am new in using posix-threads. Well, I am writing  a c-program, which creates two threads. I have a global variable, which is an array of sensor-values. The thread1 should write the values into this array. The thread 2 should read the sensor-values, after the thread1 finishes writing them. My program does not show the expected behavior. Thread 1 should write 500 values at once. But thread1 does not finish writing these 500 values at once and thread 2 begins to read corrupted values. I used a mutex, but it does not help me. The thread 1 should in all cases finish writing these 500 values. It should not be interupted, so that the thread 2 can read the actual/correct values. Here is my whole code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

int sensors_values[500];
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void  *writeSensorValues (void * msg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("%s\n", (char*)msg);
    for (int i=0; i<500; i++) {
        sensors_values[i] = i;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}

void *readSensorValues (void *msg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("%s:", (char*) msg);
    for (int i=0; i<500; i++) {
        printf(" %d",sensors_values[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}

int main () {
    pthread_t thread1,thread2;

    char * msg1 = "thread1";
    char * msg2 = "thread2";
    memset(sensors_values,-1,500);

    pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,writeSensorValues, (void*)msg1);
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,readSensorValues, (void*)msg2);

    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2,NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to get the expected behavior?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the writer will lock the mutex before the reader does. You might want to use one or two semaphores instead.

Comment: Also, `memset(sensors_values,-1,500);` should be `memset(sensors_values,-1,500*sizeof(int));`

Comment: To expand on the "use a semaphore" notion, the easiest method here is to have the `readSensorValues` function do a `sem_wait` before reading the sensor values, and have the `writeSensorValues` function do `sem_post`.  Set the initial value to 0 with `sem_init`.  If you want the two functions to be "interleaved" you ditch the mutex and do a single post/wait for each loop iteration.  Either way, you have a classic producer/consumer problem where a lone semaphore is the most basic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,

```
memset(sensors_values,-1,500);
```

should be

```
memset(sensors_values,0xFF,sizeof(sensors_values));
```

The third argument is the number of *bytes* to set.

This bug is causing only a quarter or an eighth of the array to be initialized, which might lead you to believe one thread was interrupting the other, but that's an incorrect diagnosis.

---

> *thread1 does not finish writing these 500 values at once and thread 2 begins to read corrupted values.*

That's not possible. The mutex does indeed prevent this. The following are only two possible outputs (with the fix mentioned above):

- thread1 (writeSensorValues) gets the lock first.

  > thread1
  >   thread2: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499

and

- thread2 (readSensorValues) gets the lock first.

  > thread2: -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
  >   thread1

---

If you wanted to make sure the writer runs before the reader, you could use the following:

```
pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t initial_write_done_cond;
int initial_write_done = 0;

void *writeSensorValues (void * msg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    ...
    initial_write_done = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&initial_write_done_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}

void *readSensorValues (void * msg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while (!initial_write_done)
        pthread_cond_wait(&initial_write_done_cond,&lock);

    ...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}

...

    pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&initial_write_done_cond,NULL);
```

It makes no sense to use threads in your program since the code is forced to execute sequentially, so I presume this is just a prototype of a larger program. Specifically, I presume the threads are suppose to write and read the sensors in a loop. In such a program, the above code will ensure that a write happens before any reads. (The `pthread_yield` solution posted by 4386427 could easily result in 100% CPU in such a program. In fact, I can't fathom a scenario where it's appropriate to use threads and where that solution is appropriate.)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a global flag to ensure that the writer runs first.

```
int write_done = 0;
```

Then inside the writer code do `write_done = 1;` just before unlocking the mutex.

In the reader do

```
void *readSensorValues (void *msg) {
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if (write_done == 1) break;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        pthread_yield();   // you could also add a short sleep 
                           // to avoid high CPU usage
    }

    .....
```

*EDIT*

As commented by @Dmitri a condition might be a more clean solution. I find this one less complex but see the answer by @ikegami for use of condition.

Comment: 1) The question isn't about making the writer run first, it's about not having the reader interrupt the writer. /// 2) I don't see when that would ever be the right solution. It's either a 100% CPU loop, or extremely more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Or use a condition, and wait (with the mutex locked) like `while(!write_done) pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);` (and signal the condition after writing, of course)